# Вывод каталогов и файлов в один DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Суть такова, есть DataGrid и 2 списка с типом FileInfo и DirectoryInfo.

Main.xaml

```
<DataGrid Name="ViewFiles" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemDirectory}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя файла" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Тип файла" Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Размер файла" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Length}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

VM

```
public List<FileInfo> ItemDirectory { get; set; }
```

Model

```
public List<FileInfo> GetDirectory(MainViewModel vm)
{
    //if (vm.SelectedLocalDisk == null || vm.SelectedLocalDisk == "")
    //    return null;

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
    List<DirectoryInfo> dirs = dir.GetDirectories().ToList();
    List<FileInfo> files = dir.GetFiles().ToList();

    return files;
}
```

Никак не могу сообразить, каким образом вывести в один Grid и каталоги и файлы.

Comment: Очевидно, что нужно составлять один список и его уже привязывать.

Comment: тогда каким образом можно соединить 2 списка с разными типами данных, если они не преобразовываются в друг друга? Может есть какой нибудь тип данных, к которому можно привести и FileInfo и DirectoryInfo?

Comment: Ну создаете класс, в нем делаете свойства, которые вам понадобятся (имя, путь к примеру и размер), делаете `public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Items { get; set; }` и загоняете туда все, что вам надо.

Comment: О, спасибо, что то сам до этого не додумался)